# Will there be a conflict if the account in salesforce is dormant in synching to mail chimp?

Tags: email, account, sync, mail-chimp

What is the effect of Salesforce dormant account in synching to mailchimp. Will these dormant account can receive emails from mailchimp?

Comment: You will have to check with Mailchimp support or the vendor who provides your sync tool.